# Junit Assertion Error - Getting error even though Expected and actual output are exactly same

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I am getting the following error even if the expected and actual output is exactly similar.

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: java.util.ArrayList@2bbf180e<[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]> but was: java.util.ArrayList@163e4e87<[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]>
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:182)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:177)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:1141)
at parseCsvTest$ExampleTests.shouldHandleSimpleInputs(parseCsvTest.java:17)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
```

Test cases were written by someone else as I am doing an online assessment on a website so I am not sure how the tests are written.

Here is my code.

```
public class Challenge {
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> parseCsv(
    String csv,
    String separator,
    String quote
) {
    
    String[] splitted = csv.split("\n");
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i< splitted.length; i++) {

      String[] st = splitted[i].split(separator);

      String string = new String();
      for (int j = 0; j < st.length; j++) {
        string += st[j];
        if (j != st.length - 1) {
          string += ", ";
        }
     }

     ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
     temp.add(string);
     result.add(temp);
    }
  
  return result;
}
```

}

Comment: It will be more descriptive if you share the test method as well.

Comment: @nejlasahin I have just added the code. Please check and let me know what's wrong.

Comment: Read what nejlasahin wrote above.

Answer (score 2):

Objects `ArrayList@2bbf180e` and `ArrayList@163e4e87` are not equals hence the error.

You can use JUnit 5 `Assertions.assertIterableEquals` it asserts that expected and actual iterables are deeply equal.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertIterableEquals(java.lang.Iterable,java.lang.Iterable)

Comment: `assertIterableEquals` will still fail if the deepest elements are not equal, e.g. when comparing `List<List<Integer>>` with `List<List<Long>>`.

Comment: @RobSpoor indeed, It should fail because the deepest elements are not equal. And this is what the unit test is meant for.

Comment: @roshan1892 did `assertIterableEquals` solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`List` explicitly states that a `List.equals` implementation must return `true` if the argument is also a `List`, and the two lists have equal elements in the same order. That means that, despite what [Issam El-atif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73835492/1180351) said, you should be able to use `Assertions.assertEquals`. `assertIterableEquals` is indeed necessary when trying to compare two collections of different types, e.g. a `List` and a `Set`.

In your case, the equality check fails. However, the two lists have the same `toString()` result. That's why you see `java.util.ArrayList@2bbf180e<[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]>` and not just `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`. The type and (identity?) hash codes are only added to the message if the unequal objects have the same `toString()` result, to avoid useless messages like `expected: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] but was: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`.

The real question now is - what's in the lists? Is one a `List<List<Integer>>` and the other a `List<List<Long>>`, a `List<List<String>>` or something like that? Are the elements of the lists even lists? In other words - does the expected list have the correct objects in it?

Edit: Issam is right if the list elements are collections of different types. `assertIterableEquals` calls itself if elements are both iterables. However, it will still fail when trying to compare a `List<List<Integer>>` with a `List<List<Long>>`. It will succeed when trying to compare a `List<List<Integer>>` with a `List<Set<Integer>>` if the nested lists and sets have the same order.

Comment: Well the return type  is ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> and I am returning the same type from a method as well. I have added a code, Please check. Let me know if anything if wrong in my code.

Comment: So the actual structure is `ArrayList[ArrayList[String<1, 2, 3>], ArrayList[String<4, 5, 6>]]`. Not what many expected `ArrayList[ArrayList[String<1>, String<2>, String<3>], ...]`. Can you also show how you build the expectd `ArrayList`?